# Singleton in di.dart

Tags: dependency-injection, dart

How can I create a Singleton instance in di.dart?

Seems like if I do this:

```
module = new Module()
  ..bind(GameRepository)
  ..bind(MessageFactory)
  ..bind(Broadcaster);
```

my `GameRepository` gets instantiated multiple times if when I do

`injector.get(GameRepository)`

I tried to do

`..bind(GameRepository, toValue: new GameRepository())`

and that seems to work, but it's easy because `GameRepository` has no parameter, but shouldn't there be a way to tell the di framework to bind it as a singleton without requiring me to instantiate it (and maintain its constructor call?)

edit:
@Günter, I do want a Singleton, however in my case I want to use my `GameRepository` from my redstone.dart resource AND from outside too. So I bind the `GameRepository` and then do this:

```
// To use it outside of the resource
injector = new ModuleInjector([modules.getProductionModule()]);
// To use it in redstone
app.addModule(module);
```

And now I can see that redstone hold a different reference on `GameRepository` from the one I get when I do `injector.get(GameRepository)`

I don't know if the question has become too specific though :P

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation. Do you create more than one instance of `ModuleInjector`?

Comment: Only one, but I think redstone.dart creates its own `ModuleInjector`.

Comment: Have you tried to register your module on redstone and use redstones injector everywhere (https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone/blob/472ac5144a3dbf9cc14ab32745107d38fdb14fa4/lib/server.dart#L348)?

Comment: Yeah, their injector seems to be private https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone/blob/v0.5/lib/server.dart#L581

Comment: Looks a bit like you need to create a plugin in order to be able to use a shared injector. I don't know if this is difficult and I might be totally off. I just skimmed a bit through the code in the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know DI always returns the same instance, therefore everything is a singleton. If you don't want singletons you can bind a factory. 
For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944185/217408

Answer (score 2):

How about using a factory constructor with the singleton pattern in an implementation or extension of that class

```
class GameRepositorySingleton extends GameRepository{

    static GameRepository _instance;

    factory GameRepositorySingleton (A a, B b, ...){
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new GameRepository (a, b);
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it in DI like this

```
module = new Module()
  ..bind(GameRepository, toImplementation: GameRepositorySingleton);
```

To be honest I haven't tried this out. Tell me if it works. You might have to change `extends` to `implements` if the editor complains that `GameRepository` isn't a `GameRepositorySingleton`.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing this, however I feel like it beats the purpose of using a DI framework, but that would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up doing this for now. As I need DI outside of redstone for now, I have an injector at top-level. Ideally I could share the injector with Redstone but  that doesn't seem to be possible as far as I know. I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone/issues/109). So for now, I think the best way to share a singleton instante between redstone and my code would be something along these lines.

```
// in my top-level main()
ModuleInjector injector = new ModuleInjector([new Module()..bind(GameRepository)]);

// setup of redstone
GameRepository repo = injector.get(GameRepository);
app.addModule(new Module()..bind(GameRepository, toValue: repo));

// in my redstone resource
@app.Group('/games')
class GamesResource {
  GameRepository gameRepository;

  Games(this.gameRepository);
}
```